# Error Installing charlock_holmes on centos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos

I am trying to install charlock_holmes gem on centos but i keep on getting

```
Installing charlock_holmes 0.7.6 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/charlock_holmes- 
0.7.6/ext/charlock_holmes
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180607-1811- 
1cbsady.rb
 extconf.rb --with-icu-dir=C:UsersmadprogDesktopicusourcesdistusrlocal
--with-icui18nlib=icuin --with-icudatalib=icudt
checking for main() in -licuin... no
which: no brew in
(/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby- 
2.2.5@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby- 
2.2.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/
rvm/bin:/root/bin)
checking for main() in -licuin... no


***** icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You 
may need configuration options.

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which 
can be found here:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/extensions/x86_64- 
 linux/2.2.0/charlock_holmes-0.7.6/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

An error occurred while installing charlock_holmes (0.7.6), and Bundler
cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
copyright-header was resolved to 1.0.22, which depends on
github-linguist was resolved to 6.2.0, which depends on
  charlock_holmes
```

i also tried installing libicu-dev and this is what i get 
    no package libicu-dev available.
    Error : nothing to do 
please help, thank you.

Comment: Can you post the full output you get when trying to install?

Comment: done, i just updated the post with more error details, thank you

Comment: A Google search for "libicu-dev centos" shows something named libicu-devel for me (https://www.google.com/search?q=libicu-dev+centos).  Do you want to see if installing that will fix your issue?  Let me know if it does not.

Comment: Looks like `icu4c` is missing.